# pr2, reset odom_combined

Tags: ros, navigation, odom-combined, robot-pose-ekf, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is it possible to reset the robot_pose_ekf output (it publishes odom_combined) so that the 6D robots pose is also again zero?
now to reset this pose, we restart the robot, but it would be convenient if there was just a command/service/.. to do this

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11141/pr2,-reset-odom_combined/) by [GuntherStruyf](https://answers.ros.org/users/1053/guntherstruyf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2011-09-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The robot pose ekf does not currently have a reset command/service. So, the easiest way to reset it is indeed to restart the robot.  The source code of the robot pose ekf is pretty straightforward though, so if you'd like to add this reset functionality, it would be a much appreciated contribution.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1